# <JSP> Getting value of check boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

Im stuck on getting check box's value here. Following is my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    fnChkGrp = function() {
        alert($('#reqType').val()
    )}
</script>   

<form id="frm" name="frm" method="post" action="">
    <input type="hidden" id="reqType" name="reqType"/>
    <table class="tableBB mgT10" >
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span id="reqType" style="display:block;">
                    <span class="chk"><label><input type="checkbox" id="normal" name="normal" value="normalChk"/>A</label></span>
                    <span class="chk"><label><input type="checkbox" id="urgent" name="normal" value="urgentChk"/>B</label></span>
                </span>     
            </td>

            <div class="area_btnA clfix mgB20">
                <a href="#" onclick="fnChkGrp();return false;" class="btnA"><strong>CHECK</strong></a>
            </div>
```

So when I check the "A", its its value "normalChk" should be sent through frm. 
Ans when I click on the CHECK button, its value should be displayed.
But for some reason, it doesn't work. Can anyone tell me why? and How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
if($('input[name=normal]').prop(':checked').val()==true)
{
    alert("Checked");
}
else
{
    alert("Unchecked");
}
```

**[.prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)** get the value of a property for the first element in the set of matched elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
fnChkGrp = function() {
   var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName("normal");
    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++)
    {
        if (checkboxes[i].checked)
            alert(checkboxes[i].value);
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<form id="frm" name="frm" method="post" action="">
<input type="hidden" id="reqType" name="reqType"/>
<table class="tableBB mgT10" >
<tr>

    <td>
        <span id="reqType" style="display:block;">
            <span class="chk"><label><input type="checkbox" id="normal" name="normal" value="normalChk"/>A</label></span>
            <span class="chk"><label><input type="checkbox" id="urgent" name="normal" value="urgentChk"/>B</label></span>
        </span>     
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
    <div class="area_btnA clfix mgB20">
        <a href="#" onclick="fnChkGrp();return false;" class="btnA"><strong>CHECK</strong></a>
    </div>
</form>
```